PI zero 2 w and virtualhere and otg port
I have a PC with Windows, that cannot be connected to the internet or install drivers (for security reasons) and I need to connect a dongle that I have on my server (this server has the virtualhere server) to open and use a software of dongle.
I had an idea to buy a pi zero 2 w and make my cell phone a hotspot to provide internet to the pi and a secure connection to my server. Until this step everything went well and I was able to install the virtualhere client and the pi recognizes the dongle as if it had been physically connected.
So the next step is to make sure that the pi, when connected to the PC, is recognized as if it were the dongle and forwards all the information.
It's at this stage that I have problems...
After configuring the pi with dwc2, making a script using libcomposite, reading the information from the dongle and replicating it to the USB port connected to the PC, it already detects it as a dongle and allows access to the files stored on the dongle but the dongle software does not recognizes it as a dongle just as a storage pen, despite having the correct manufacturer settings (idvendor, product...). The only thing I'm detecting that could be causing the problem are the endpoints.
I can't replicate the endpoints, despite knowing that there are 3, their addresses and configuration, I can't create a USB gadget using these endpoints. whenever I try to create the endpoints (/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/gadget/ep_01.usb) I receive the information of operation not allowed (yes, I am using sudo). I'm tired of looking for information on examples of how to create endpoints in Debian with USB Gadget but without success. Can anyone give any help or suggestions?
